# retrieving data with mongodb java driver 3.4 using find()-method with projection

Tags: java, mongodb, projection, mongodb-java, data-retrieval

I am using mongodb java driver 3.4.

In the mongodb database documents are saved according to the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595a9fc4fe3f36402b7edf0e"),
    "id" : "123",
    "priceInfo" : [
        {object1: value1}, {object2: value2}, {object3: value3}
    ]
}
```

In order to retrieve the "priceInfo"-Array of a Document with a specific id, I wrote the following code:

```
collection.find(eq("id", id)).first().projection(fields(include("priceInfo"), excludeId()));
```

I wrote this code according too the documentation, which you can find here:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html

The problem is that my IDE won't accept this code.

It's giving me the following error indication:

[image]

I have no clue why this code doesn't work. At first the IDE suggested including several classes - which I did. But after that I still got an error indication, namely the one you see above.

What's wrong with the code? How can I retrieve the priceInfo array of a Document with ID id?

********************************UPDATE**********************************

As per request, here's the whole class:

```
package DatabaseAccess;

import Models.GasStation;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.excludeId;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.fields;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.include;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Updates;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.bson.Document;


public class databaseAccess {

    private final String DB_HOST = "localhost"; 
    private final int DB_PORT = 27017;
    private final String DB_NAME = "db1"; 
    private final String DB_COLLECTION = "prices"; 
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    private final MongoDatabase database;
    private final MongoCollection<Document> collection; 

    public databaseAccess(){
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(DB_HOST, DB_PORT);
        database = mongoClient.getDatabase(DB_NAME);
        collection = database.getCollection(DB_COLLECTION);
    }


    public String readFromDB(String id){
        collection.find(eq("id", id)).first().projection(fields(include("priceInfo"), excludeId()));
        return null;     
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete code of your class (with imports).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve / find all elements of a nested array in MongoDB Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916428/how-to-retrieve-find-all-elements-of-a-nested-array-in-mongodb-java)

Comment: it's not a duplicate .... that this is an array in my case is not important. I want to get the array as a whole. I used the same code as the one providing the approved answer (apart from leaving away the "map..." part since I am as already mentioned not interested in retrieving single items from the array) ... the thing is: why does this code give me an error indication?

Comment: Please consider reading javadocs while using methods. This has helped me and sure will help you with using the APIs in the correct way. It's compile time error which tells you are not using the API correctly. Btw the answer does contain the correct usage of first with projections.

Comment: TBH, I follow the guide https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-document somehow the include keyowrd give me error just to return the _id field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're operating on chain of calls in your method.
Let's analyze each element in chain:

> MongoCollection:
>
> FindIterable< TDocument> find() - Finds all documents in  the collection.

Return type is `FindIterable<TDocument>` and you calling the next method in chain on it:

> FindIterable< TDocument>
>
> Methods inherited from interface com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterable:
>
> batchCursor, first, forEach, into, map

Okay, we are going to `MongoIterable`:

> MongoIterable< TResult>:
>
> void  first(SingleResultCallback callback) - Helper to return the first item in the iterator or null.

**That means `first(...)` is returned nothing. You're calling `projection(...)` from nothing, of course this is not applicable, so the compiler marks this as an error.**

For calling `projection(Bson projection)` you shoud have `FindIterable<T>` instance. `MongoCollection.find()` can provide you with this instance:

```
collection.find(eq("id", id)).projection(fields(include("priceInfo"), excludeId()));
```